# How to put quotes correctly in this statement

Tags: php, if-statement, quotes

I need to return an input box from a function but i could put the quotes correctly. Any one please help me to solve the error.

```
<?php
 return "
<input  style='background-color:#CCC;'type='text' name='contactName' id='contactName' value='".if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName']."' class='requiredField' />";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
<?php
 return '
<input  style="background-color:#CCC;" type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" value="'.(isset($_POST['contactName'])?$_POST['contactName']:'').'" class="requiredField" />';
```

for inline if that will output somthing use this syntax:

```
( condition ? 'the thing that will return when condition true' : 'the false returned string' )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) {$contactname=$_POST['contactName'];}
 return "<input  style='background-color:#CCC;'type='text' name='contactName' id='contactName' value='".$contactname."' class='requiredField' />";
?>
```

Comment: works fine but.your code is wrong because of xhtml. and also I think you should add `contactname='';` before if statement.

Comment: How this answer is different than **Rikesh's** answer?

Comment: rikesh's also write answer but not need define variable blank in above

Comment: @ankit - It will throw [notice](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iwFYTX) if he won't get post value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing in a single line, you can break it instead and return the value.

```
if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) {
    $value = $_POST['contactName'];
} else {
    $value = "";
}

$input  = '<input style="background-color:#CCC;" type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" ';
$input .= 'value="'. $value .'" ';
$input .= 'class="requiredField" ';
$input .= '/>';

return $input;
```

Also i can see that you are assigning a value without processing it. This is not correct.
So, it should be something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) {
        $value = stripslashes($_POST['contactName']);
    } else {
        $value = "";
    }
```

You can also use any other escape method if you are using PDO.

Comment: How this answer is different than Rikesh's answer?

Comment: I didnt check the rikesh's answer while adding my answer. It also only one answer that time.

Answer (score -1):

Another  simple solution

```
    <?php 
     if(isset($_POST['contactName']))
        {
         return "<input  style='background-color:#CCC;'type='text' name='contactName' id='contactName' value='".$_POST['contactName']."' class='requiredField' />";
        }
     ?>
```